# Pass toggling Boolean from service to controller

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, boolean, toggle

I want to show/hide an element based on the Boolean value that is changing in my service. I want the change of this Boolean to happen in my service so multiple controllers can access the true or false value, but I am having trouble returning this value to one or more controllers. Currently I'm only able to pass one value which is false, although the value does show it's changing in my service. Here is an example of my controller...

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .service('ThisService', function(){
       function toggleDisplay(){
          return displayElement = !displayElement;
       }
   });

   .controller('ThisCtrl', function (thisService, $scope) {

        function init(){
            $scope.displayElement = ThisService.toggleDisplay();
        }

        $scope.toggleElement = function(){
            $scope.displayElement = ThisService.toggleDisplay();
        }

        init();
    });
```

My HTML...

```
<div ng-show="displayElement">Show hide me</div>
<button ng-click='toggleElement()'></button>
```

Can you please tell me how to return the true/false value to my controller correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a value and then toggle that in your service. However, your service definition is not valid, you have a semi-colon in the middle of your chain of modules and you define your service with the name "ThisService", but then you try to reference it in your controller as "thisService" (it's case sensitive).

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .value("DisplayElement", { value: true })
    .service("ThisService", function(DisplayElement) {
        this.toggleDisplay = function() {
          return DisplayElement.value = !DisplayElement.value;
        }
    })
    .controller("ThisCtrl", function(ThisService, $scope) {
        function init() {
            $scope.displayElement = ThisService.toggleDisplay();
        }

        $scope.toggleElement = function() {
            $scope.displayElement = ThisService.toggleDisplay();
        }

        init();
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ThisCtrl">
    <div ng-show="displayElement">Show hide me</div>
    <button ng-click="toggleElement()">Toggle Display</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/es1re5z5/1/)

You could even eliminate the service and just access the value directly in your controller (you'd have to inject it first).